# Launching RecyclerView crashes app

Tags: java, android

I'm having this problem in both apps that I am trying to build. When I launch a RecyclerView, the app crashes. I've already compared my adapter code to multiple sources so I don't believe the problem lies there. I am unable to pinpoint what is wrong.

This is just a very simple checklist. 100 rows each with a number,edit text,checkbox, and a button

checklist.java

```
public class checkList extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);

    numbers[] mNumbers = new numbers[100];

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    for (int i = 0; i<mNumbers.length; i++) {
        mNumbers[i].setInt(i + 1);
    }

    myAdapter = new myAdapter(mNumbers);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


}
}
```

numbers.java

```
public class numbers {

private int mInt;

public int getInt() {
    return mInt;
}

public void setInt(int anInt) {
    mInt = anInt;
}
}
```

adapter.java

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private numbers[] mNumbers;

public myAdapter (numbers[] numbers) {
    mNumbers = numbers;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_slot, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindNumbers(mNumbers[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNumbers.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView numberText;
    EditText checklistText;
    Button deleteButton;
    CheckBox checkDisBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        numberText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        checklistText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        checkDisBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }

    public void bindNumbers(numbers numbers) {
        numberText.setText(numbers.getInt() + "");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post your exception from logcat.

Comment: problem is on line number 27. which line is that. Also, edit your question to update instead of posting update as an answer.

Comment: In the checklist class: for (int i = 0; i<mNumbers.length; i++) {
            mNumbers[i].setInt(i + 1);
        }

Comment: You've dimensioned the array, but you need to instantiate a `new numbers()` object for each index.

Comment: thanks mike. i got it solved now